# How to use Swiper JS method in Svelte

Tags: svelte, swiper.js

I want to use slideNext() method in Swiper JS. However, from the [documentation of Swiper JS for Svelte](https://swiperjs.com/svelte), there is no example on showing how to access to method in Svelte. In React, there is a hook called useSwiper but no such thing in Svelte. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API is a bit weird. It should be using a bindable prop but you need to handle the `swiper` event instead to get the API instance.

```html
<script>
  // ...
  let swiper;
</script>

<Swiper on:swiper={e => swiper = e.detail[0]}>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>

<button type=button on:click={() => swiper.slidePrev()}>Previous</button>
<button type=button on:click={() => swiper.slideNext()}>Next</button>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/b3b8cc160e614806a807cd1de9e0f8f7?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have marked your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since Swiper JS no longer supports Svelte directly (and soon will probably drop support for all other frameworks), we should now use Swiper as a custom HTML element (web component) [Swiper component](https://swiperjs.com/element). Below is an example of how to use Swiper in Svelte:

```
// App.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
  register(); // register swiper components

  // ...
</script>



// SomeComponent.svelte
<script lang="ts">
import {type SwiperContainer} from 'swiper/element/bundle';
import {onMount} from "svelte";

let swiperEl: SwiperContainer|undefined;
let swiperNextElem: HTMLElement|undefined;
let swiperPrevElem: HTMLElement|undefined;
onMount(() => {
    if(swiperEl != undefined && swiperNextElem != undefined && swiperPrevElem != undefined) {
        const swiperParams = {
            navigation: {
                nextEl: swiperNextElem,
                prevEl: swiperPrevElem,
            },
            slidesPerView: 1,
            loop: true,
        }

        // now we need to assign all parameters to Swiper element
        Object.assign(swiperEl, swiperParams);

        // and now initialize it
        swiperEl.initialize();
    }
});
</script>


<div>
    <swiper-container init="false" bind:this={swiperEl}>
        <swiper-slide><div>CUSTOM ELEMENT</div></swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide><div>CUSTOM ELEMENT</div></swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide><div>CUSTOM ELEMENT</div></swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>

    <div bind:this={swiperPrevElem}>Prev</div>
    <div bind:this={swiperNextElem}>Next</div>
</div>
```